# HP P/N 1150-7931. REV 5.3

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, usb

I to have found this bored I mine precious metal out of computer boards so anything and everything crosses my Plate sooner or later I am not an electrical engineer or some kind of computer genius so in layman‘s terms could somebody tell me how to connect this to my laptop and send me a picture of what the cord looks like and What it looks like connected to your laptop I would appreciate it very much thank you I am interested in the whole concept of electrical engineering but know nothing about it

Comment: What is it? A printer? A spectrum analyzer? A mass spectrometer? A diode? HP has made all these things in its history. What does the connector on this thing look like? A photo of it might help us help you.

Comment: It appears to be a wireless printer card, so I suspect a cord would be superfluous. Anyhow, this is off-topic here, we generally deal with designing and building, not using, devices.

Answer (score 1):

The HP P/N 1150-7931 is a wireless card from an HP printer.  You cannot directly connect it to your laptop without modifying it with a USB port, which oddly enough someone has done here: https://alexkaltsas.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/hacking-a-printerss-wifi-module/